# Problems with print labels continuously (Zebra Printer)

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I have 44x15 mm labels. When i prints this labels continuously first label prints good then 4 labels bad and then 1 label good (see in picture). How I can solve this problem.
Thanks!

My zpl code

```
^XA
^LH0,0
^FO100,20^AD,30
^FD5^FS
^FO15,70^AE,25
^FDBT20^FS
^FO30,120^AD,30
^FDRPMI^FS
^FO425,78^AD,28
^FD5^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly solve this, I need some additional information. What is the printer DPMM? At 8 DPMM, only the first two lines are shown on a label. Also, there is no attached image.

That said, nothing in your format suggests that this is more than one label long. You might want to split each label into it's own format definition. If this is a single label definition, you also might want to look at the Field Interactions section of the ZPL programming guide (Page 1215 in my copy) to help with the columnar justifications. That will help you with your field origin calculations.

Finally, you will probably want to add a label length (^LL180 for 12 DPMM) at the beginning to help the printer out.